# eth0 device features

Tags: c, linux, udev

I'm currently using libudev to get MAC addresses of network interfaces (net subsystem, address). I would like also to distinguish between specific types of those devices (wlan, ethernet, virtual vpn,...). Is this possible to get this information from this output (by libudev of course)?

```
/sbin/udevadm info -a -p /sys/class/net/eth0
```

I probably can't distinguish by name because names as eth0 mean nothing in fact because you can change them. As far as I can see there is only big difference between my interfaces in "features" field.

For eth0:
ATTR{features}=="0x4180"

For wlan0:
ATTR{features}=="0x2000"

For tap0:
ATTR{features}=="0x0"

Is this a possibility to get a specific type of device? Or is this direction completely wrong? If it is ok - is there any specification available what those numbers/bits exactly mean? Thanks for help.